# Unable to assign permissions to create articles

Tags: articles, acl

I am unable to assign permission to create articles in a specific category. ACL permissions are set to their default values. I have edited the category in question, selected permissions, and given the Registered group permission to **create** and **edit own**.

When a registered user navigates to the category listing page, "New" button appears -- but the button is clicked the link, Joomla shows an error about "Unauthorized to view that resource...."

Is there any other setting that must be set to accomplish this?

Comment: I'm unable to replicate this issue, please have a look on this screencast. Did you missed something? https://www.dropbox.com/s/sqb9dsfuyllfhs0/registersubmission.mp4?raw=1

Comment: That's exactly what I've done. I ran through the steps on a dev site and it worked as expected -- so something odd is going on with the main site. Any suggestions for how to troubleshoot this further?

Comment: Have you tried to Clear / Purge your Joomla cache from the administrator page? Or maybe you want to try to repair joomla tables in case maybe it get crashed?